# Rename photos to match video titles

Tags: bash, files, rename

I have a mostly automated media server and currently have everything going into one folder and being sorted out by file extension into the correct locations.

At the moment the photos are coming in named "folder.jpg" and I need to rename them to match the movie name.

What it looks like now:
Before:

- /Directory/

  - folder.jpg
  - Movie.mp4
  - Movie.xml

What I need it to look like:
After:

- /Directory/

  - Movie.jpg
  - Movie.mp4
  - Movie.xml

How would I go about matching the jpg to mp4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
for movie in ./*/*.mp4; do mv -- "${movie%/*}/folder.jpg" "${movie%.mp4}.jpg"; done
```

`${movie%/*}` and `${movie%.mp4}` are both examples of *suffix removal*. `${movie%/*}` returns the directory that the movie file is in and `${movie%.mp4}` returns the name of the movie file minus the extension `.mp4`.

#### Example

Consider three directories, `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3`, with the files:

```
$ ls -1 */*
dir1/Animal Crackers.mp4
dir1/Animal Crackers.xml
dir1/folder.jpg
dir2/folder.jpg
dir2/Monkey Business.mp4
dir2/Monkey Business.xml
dir3/Duck Soup.mp4
dir3/Duck Soup.xml
dir3/folder.jpg
```

Now, run our command:

```
$ for movie in ./*/*.mp4; do mv -- "${movie%/*}/folder.jpg" "${movie%.mp4}.jpg"; done
```

After running our command, the files are:

```
$ ls -1 */*
dir1/Animal Crackers.jpg
dir1/Animal Crackers.mp4
dir1/Animal Crackers.xml
dir2/Monkey Business.jpg
dir2/Monkey Business.mp4
dir2/Monkey Business.xml
dir3/Duck Soup.jpg
dir3/Duck Soup.mp4
dir3/Duck Soup.xml
```

#### Multiple line version

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
for movie in ./*/*.mp4
do
    mv -- "${movie%/*}/folder.jpg" "${movie%.mp4}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: +1 nice one. One minor question: is there any reason to use `./*/*.mp4` instead of simply`*/*.mp4` without the leading dot?

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't working for me with the single line. Changed to multi-line version and it works great! Thank you.

Comment: @Sparhawk With `*/*.mp4`, there is the possibility that the path will start with a dash, `-`, which could cause `mv` or another such program to treat the path as an option leading to surprising and bad results.  Consequently, it is a good habit to start paths with `./` so that the path will never be misinterpreted as an option.  (Here, out of habit, I also used `mv --` so consider the two together as a belt-and-suspenders approach.)

Comment: @RobertW That's curious:  I used the single-line version for testing.  Anyway, glad one of the versions works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @John1024. And excellent analogy!

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -execdir bash -c ' [[ -f folder.jpg ]] && mv -v folder.jpg "$(basename {} .mp4).jpg"' \;
```